# Creating Python 2.7 virtualenv gets stuck on Installing setuptools, pip, wheel

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, virtualenv

I am setting up a new project folder in PyCharm that requires Python 2.7. When I try to create the virtualenv the install gets stuck on 'Intalling setuptools, pip, wheel'.

I tried creating this venv in PyCharms interface and when that did not work I also tried doing this in the terminal as well. Both get stuck on the same message.

From the terminal I cd to project directory and run the command below and it just gets stuck.

```
virtualenv -p C:/Python27/python.exe venv27
```

I am not having this issue with various versions of Python 3. What could be the issue here with Python 2?

My internet connection is fine and since I can create the venv with Python 3 it must be something else.

Comment: I have the same issue. I am unable to create virtualenv by both virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper. I think pip hasn't been installed correctly or there is some problem with one of the python files as when I run the command `pip freeze`, it shows me the packages and then I have to explicitly cancel the process using `Ctrl+C`.